# The Post-Predeploymet SharePoint does not recognize some terms

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, powershell

In SharePoint Post-deployment command Line I have: `%windir%\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell -File "$(ProjectDir)Scripts\Post-Deployment\Script.Post-Deployment.ps1"`

After running the deployment I received this error:

> The term 'Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogMetadataObject' is not recognized
>   as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
>   that the path is correct and try  again.

Does anybody has a solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you load the SharePoint snap-in, put this at the beginning of the script:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```